# Getting the vcores and memory from machine type

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to programmatically get the vcores and memory for a particular gce machine time using python

Comment: Do you want to run python on the machine to get the information or are you asking about exploiting a Google API from another machine?

Comment: Hey... I was looking for the second option... Suppose I have a machine type 'n1-standard-4' , it should return me 4 vcores and 15 GB.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the specification of your VM's, you can use this [API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/machineTypes/get).

> The field **guestCpusf** will return you the number of virtual CPUs
>   that are available to the instance, and the field memoryMb, will
>   return the amount of physical memory available to the instance,
>   defined in MB.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer is correct if he asked for the REST API. Update to include Python code to make your post answer the question asked. Otherwise, move your answer to be a comment on the question as it is not an answer to the question asked.